# How to install sklearn on visual studio 2019?

Tags: python, visual-studio, scikit-learn, package

I'm working on a sample project with python language and visual studio 2019 IDE and I want to know how/where can I install packages like "sklearn"?

When I run my project I encounter with this error :

```
  Message=No module named 'sklearn'
  Source=C:\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication.py", line 12, in <module>
  from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
```

I was looking on the Internet and found [this link about scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/install.html) but it doesn't help to resolve my issue.

Comment: Everything is mentioned in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019

Comment: @AviThour oh Thanks this is the what I was looking

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal in VSCode (Ctrl + Shift + ~) and run the below command

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal > select cmd then type

```
 py -m pip install scikit-learn
```